# Using singleton class for sharing instance of database between activities?

Tags: android, database, singleton

Hey! I want to use a singleton class, because if I open the database every activity I get "Leak found"( that happens because I open the database even if it is already open ) . I create a singleton class , but I don't know how should I use it.

Here is my class:

```
package com.ShoppingList;

import com.ShoppingList.databases.DbAdapter;

public class DbManager {

    DbAdapter db;

    // singleton
    private static DbManager instance = null;

    private DbManager() {

    }

    public static DbManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DbManager();
        return instance;
    }

    public void setinstance(DbAdapter db){
        this.db=db;
    }

    public DbAdapter getinstancedb(){
        return db;
    }
}
```

In the first activity I put :

```
db = new DbAdapter(this);
        db.open();
        DbManager.getInstance().setinstance(db);
```

and for the next activity : DbManager.getInstance().getinstancedb(); but I get force close for second activity.

Can anyone help me how to use it? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class and create there an instance of `DbAdapter`. This way it will be shared by all your activities.

Comment: ok...but here is what I don't understand-should I open it in only one activity.the first one?And after that share it..that means it is opened for all the others????

Comment: Good point. Put some wrapper methods for `open` and `close` in your `DbManager` and call them in each activity, as needed. If you do this, you might as well just forego the `Application` extension.

Comment: Am facut asta..So the rule is:in every activity I open my DB in onCreate() and close it in onDestroy()????

Comment: Not necessarily. It is possible that `onDestroy()` never gets called. When you need something from the database, open it, grab the data and close it right after.

Comment: But hear me out:Let's say I have an activity in which I receive some GPS data....and I've implemented onLocationChanged() method...so each time new GPS update arrive I insert them into my DB...In such cases when do I close my DB?

Comment: Right where you need it: in `onLocationChanged()`, after writing the updates.

Comment: Dar fratele meu....onLocationChange() este apelata de fiecare data cand primesc date GPS.Sa spunem ca  ma deplasez pe o ruta...si primesc date GPS all along the way..eu deschid baza de date in onCreate() ...inserez date in ea in onLocationChanged() si o inchid..primesc din nou update de date GPS onLocationChanged() se apeleaza din nou,incerc sa inserez in baza de date si ghici ce?..FORCE CLOSE ca doara baza de date e inchisa:P

Comment: `open` -> write -> `close`, all in `onLocationChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because db has the same context and life cycle of your first activity.  Make your methods public and make them do all the setup/teardown necessary to return your desired result.

Comment: But it shouldn't be in its current implementation.  If you call it without opening the db and calling getinstance() & setinstance() it will force close.  In the getinstancedb() you'd have to do all the setup and teardown as I mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the leak warning. Are you closing your db manager connection in `onDestroy()`?

Comment: yes I do it in every activity...I open it in onCreate(0 and close it in onDestroy()...:)